# How to check if certificate is present in HttpRequestMessage without triggering renegotiate?

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl, certificate

I have an incoming HttpRequestMessage and want to check if there is a client certificate attached to the request.  I see 2 ways to do this:

```
request.GetClientCertificate()
request.GetRequestContext().Certificate
```

However, both of these cause an SSL renegotiation to the client if a certificate is not already present in the request.  I want to just get the certificate that's already there -or- return null if none is already present.  Is there a way to do that?